# Read/Write complex graphics to KML

Tags: c#, arcgis, kml, esri, kmz

im using version 100.12 or Esri Runtime nugget
I want to read/write complex graphic between old and new system

In my system I have a very specific layer that  can have all type of supported graphics(all graphics are created from the sketch editor)
in my layer:

- Each graphic have unique label with color, font style and more
- the polylines can have line symbol that is loaded from .stylx
- polygons cab gave line and  fill symbol that is loaded from .stylx

Furthermore  I have  3 special cases which are all point geometry with different symbol(because i cant create, for example text symbol from the sketch editor)

- TextSymbol
- PictureMarkerSymbols
- [MSS Symbol which uses 3rd party   software](https://www.gs-soft.com/CMS/de/produkte/mssstick-mss-und-milx/mss)

[i followed the demo as described here](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/wpf/sample-code/create-and-save-kml-file/)
but beside reading and writing simple point, polyline and polygon it seems i cant do much more(?)
is there a way

Convert  any graphic to kml object
extended the built-in kml parser
use other built in object(s)
other